# Error Deploying Java App on OpenShift Express

Tags: deployment, cloud, openshift

I am attempting to deploy my java app to OpenShift Express.

The app runs fine on my local tomcat and on CloudFoundry platform. I have created the app in the management console, and have then pushed my app code to the openshift created git repository.

When I perform the push, I see that the maven build has completed successfully with no errors, however, if I then check the status of the app (using the command: `rhc app status`) then I get the following errors displayed:

```
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.deploy(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 5 more
2012/04/04 15:01:42,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".DEPENDENCIES: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"ROOT.war\""}}
2012/04/04 15:01:42,462 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 320ms
2012/04/04 15:01:42,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".DEPENDENCIES: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "ROOT.war"
2012/04/04 15:01:42,539 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".DEPENDENCIES: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"ROOT.war\""}}}}
```

As well as this error, I can see the end of a stacktrace, so have tried to tail the logs of the application using rhc-tail-file command, but when I do that I get the following error: `Error in trying to tail files`

Has anyone come across this or have any advice on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and SSH into your application using the same UUID and hostname as your git repository. If you go into appname/logs you should be able to see the complete logs.
Once you get that you should have a better sense of the error.

Comment: Yep, thanks - managed to get this working following some feedback from the redhat guys - turned out that I had not installed the ssh package on my cygwin installation, which was why the rhc-tail-files wasnt working. Updated my install and all working fine now.